# Average power dissipation in radar

Tags: power-dissipation, radar

Hello there here i want to calculate average power dissipation of radar

My question is here

[image]

i tried to solve it this way

Average power = peak power*Duty cycle

here transmitted power is 300kW and efficiency of radar transmitter is 60 %.
so my power is 180W and i calculate it with duty cycle. so i am getting 18 kW.

but my expected answer is 20.9kW. can anyone tell me why I am wrong??

thanks!

Comment: Draw a graph showing power for one complete cycle of the radar pulse. The y-axis should be labelled power. The x-axis should be labelled time. Find the average over one cycle. That is what the question is asking.

Comment: @Beginner, would you like a more rigorous (and hopefully more intuitive) answer to this question? The equations will require some simple calculus, or we could use simple algebra but the equations will not be as elegant.

Comment: yes i would like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dissipation would be power that you put in that doesn't get radiated. So, 90% of the time, it dissipates 1000W, correcting for duty cycle is 900W. 300kW RF at 10% duty cycle would be 30kW. That's at 60% efficiency, so that means 40% of the input power is dissipated. 30/0.4*0.6 = 20 kW. Total dissipation is 20.9 kW. That sucker is going to need a really big heat sink!

Comment: I remember working with an airborne search radar - 2.5MW per pulse in long range search mode. The magnetron was in an oil bath.

Answer (score 5):

OK, here's an edit that explains why the answer is 20.9 kW. The question is actually asking for radar power dissipation and not input power so, if the radar is emitting 300 kW at 60% efficiency then the input power is 500 kW and the losses are 200 kW - that's an average power loss over the whole cycle of 20 kW - add that the the 900 watts lost when the pulse isn't there and you get 20.9 kW.

## Original answer:

For 90% of the time the power is 1 kW. That's an average power of 900 watts.

For 10% of the time the power is 300 kW/0.6 = 500 kW or, an average power of 50 kW. Total average power is 50.9 kW.

I don't see how the answer can be 20.9 kW.

> here transmitted power is 300kW and efficiency of radar transmitter is
>   60 %. so my power is 180W and i calculate it with duty cycle. so i am
>   getting 18 kW.

You calculated that wrong - it should be 300 kW/0.6.

Comment: thanks. power required during pulse off period is 1kw.  then how you calculate 900 W??

Comment: @Beginner First sentence: 90% of 1kW.

Comment: I also agree that it should be 50.9kW. Even if they're looking for RMS power under the assumption that 50kW is peak power, the answer would be ~36.5kW. Either the answer is wrong or you've missed a critical piece of information from the question.

Comment: yes i have given answer from answer key. and answer key may be wrong

Comment: i can't understand this 300 kW/0.6 = 500 kW

Comment: i think power should be multiplied with efficieny

Comment: @Beginner If the transmitter outputs 300 kW then what would be the input power to the inefficient transmitter (hint: you can't create power if it isn't there). I've also amended my answer having re-read the text a few times.

Comment: Efficiency tells you how many watts of RF you get for every watt of electricity that you put in. In this case, you have the RF wattage and you want the input power, so you divide.

Comment: Actually, you're all wrong - question is asking about dissipation. So divide by 0.6, then multiply by 0.4. I think the key is correct.

Comment: @alex.forencich you need to update your browser. I showed how the answer is 20.9 kW some time ago.

Answer (score 2):

Power transmitted=300 kW

D=10% (duty cycle)

Efficiency=60%

**PULSE ON**

\$Efficiency = \frac{\text{Power Transmitted}}{\text{Power Delivered}}.\$

\$\text{Power delivered}=\frac{\text{Power Transmitted}}{0.6}=\text{500 kW}.\$

The difference between Power Delivered and Power Transmitted is the power dissipated during PULSE ON (i.e 200 kW, since the duty cycle is 10%, 10% of the time T).

\$Power Dissipated(ON) = \text{200 kW×0.1 T} = \text{20 kW×T}\$.

Here T is the time period.

**PULSE OFF**

Power Dissipated= 1kW. This occurs 90% of the time(duty cycle=10%).

\$Power Dissipated(OFF) = \text{1 kW×0.9 T = 0.9 kW×T.} \$

\$\text{Average Power Dissipation} =\frac{\text{20.9 kW×T}}{T}=\text{20.9 kW}\$